# product of vectors is zero then products of basis is.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coding-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over a finite field $F_q$ and let $\{v_1, v_2, . . . , v_k\}$ be
a basis of $V$. Show that the following two statements are equivalent:

(i) $v\cdot v^\prime = 0$ for all $v, v^\prime\in V$,

(ii) $v_i\cdot v_j = 0$ for all $i, j \in \{1, 2, . . . , k\}$.
(Note: this shows that it suffices to check (ii) when we need to determine
whether a given linear code is self-orthogonal.)
(u.v is inner product)
(i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) is obvious as product of basis are $0$ then product of vector is.

{{
Let $v = (v_1, v_2, . . . , v_n),w = (w_1,w_2, . . . , w_n) \in F_q^n$.
The scalar product (also known as the dot product or the Euclidean inner
product) of $v$ and $w$ is defined as
$$v \cdot w = v_1w_1 + ·· ·+v_nw_n \in F_q .$$
The two vectors $v$ and $w$ are said to be orthogonal if $v \cdot w = 0.$}}

but the other side is confusing.

Thanks for help

Comment: How is the product of two vectors defined? Are you writing about an *inner product vector space*? Please specify!

Comment: yeap inner product i added this information.

Comment: And how's an inner product defined over a *finite* field?? Some particular generalization may, perhaps, be defined, but what is being used **here** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vector's a linear combination of basis vectors, and the standard properties of the dot product (ditributivity and the like) show that if the basis vectors are orthogonal (including each being orthogonal to itself) then all pairs of vectors are orthogonal.

Just to give a small example, if $v\cdot v=v\cdot w=w\cdot w=0$, then $$(av+bw)\cdot(cv+dw)=(ac)v\cdot v+(ad)v\cdot w+(bc)w\cdot v+(bd)w\cdot w=0+0+0+0=0$$

Comment: I have given you what you want. Note what I wrote: if the basis vectors are orthogonal, then all pairs are orthogonal.